# Match string of odd length

Tags: regex

Im trying to construct a regular expression to just match if the length of the string is odd. I have not had any success so far.

2313432  - true

12 - false

121111111111111 - true

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to use regex for this?

Comment: I understand there may be a particular reason you need to use regexes, and I don't want to second-guess that; but if you were just after any solution, I assume you could just use (string.size % 2) == 1 (in whatever language)?

Comment: just trying to learn regex :)

Comment: @user338128, @Smashery: You never know... maybe he's just trying to get a handle on regular expressions.

Comment: Now what if i want to just match odd length for strings only containing [a-zAz], sorry kinda on a tangent

Comment: Dacto, one of the _first_ things you should learn about regexes is where they're suitable and where they're not :-) By all means play with this sort of stuff for your education, just be aware that it's a bad use of them. So many people ask about how to do this or that with regexes when there's usually a simpler way (a la Smashery above).

Comment: And, if you want odd strings for a particular character class (e.g., `[A-Za-z]`), just use that instead of `.`.

Comment: @Dacto: Just take the full stops in our answers, and replace them with `[a-zA-Z]`. (In order not to have to write them out twice in a row in the grouping parentheses, you can instead write `[a-zA-Z]{2}` to signify that you just want two of the last item. You can do the same with the `.` character, but why waste four characters for `.{2}` when you can just use two for `..`?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want this regular expression:

`^.(..)*$`

This says, match one character, then zero or more sets of two characters, all of which is anchored to the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like: `^(..)*.$` ?

Comment: @Dacto: I was going to say the same thing, but he had made an edit to his answer. Refresh and you'll see that this is now correct EXCEPT that it will not match strings of length 1. (I have no idea why people are upvoting it, now or before the edit!)

Comment: `'^((..)+.|.)$'` adds a match for a length 1 string (I'd still use `strlen()` though)

Comment: @Seth: That regex is more complicated than it needs to be. (See my answer)